# Angular + Websockets + Spring-Boot receiving duplicate entries on the client

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I'm connecting to Spring-Boot sever over websockets to receive logs of a particular device by it's uuid.

logsStompConfig.ts

```
import { StompConfig } from '@stomp/ng2-stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
export const logsStompConfig: StompConfig = {
    url: () => new SockJS('http://localhost:9000/gs-guide-websocket'),
    headers: {},
    heartbeat_in: 0,
    heartbeat_out: 20000,
    reconnect_delay: 1000,
    debug: false
};
```

logs.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { StompService } from "@stomp/ng2-stompjs";
import { Message } from "@stomp/stompjs";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
@Injectable()
export class LogsService {
    private stomp_subscription: Observable<Message>;
    constructor(private stompService: StompService) {
        this.stomp_subscription = stompService.subscribe('/topic/logs');
    }
    connect(uuid: string) {
         this.stompService.publish('/app/ws', JSON.stringify({uuid}));
    return this.stomp_subscription.map((message: Message) => message);
    }
}
```

logs.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
import { Message } from "@stomp/stompjs";
import { LogsService } from "logs.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'logs',
    templateUrl: 'logs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./logs.component.scss']
})
export class LogsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private logsService: LogsService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.logsService.connect('666-771').subscribe(message => {
            console.log(message);
        });
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

logs.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { StompService, StompConfig } from "@stomp/ng2-stompjs";
import { logsStompConfig } from "./logsStompConfig";
import { LogsService } from "./logs.service";
import { LogsComponent } from './logs.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [LogsComponent],
    providers: [
        StompService,
        {
            provide: StompConfig,
            useValue: logsStompConfig
        },
        LogsService
    ],
    exports: [LogsComponent]
})
export class LogsModule { }
```

According to chrome devtools, I'm doing publish multiple times instead of once and as a result, getting duplicate entries on the client.

Am I missing some parameter or something?
Interestingly enough, the guide from Spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ gives the same weird result.